# Client side database sync options

Tags: node.js, sails.js, data-synchronization, waterline

Is there any nodejs library that we can use to sync database between client and server while using Sailsjs. I know Meteor has a out of the box library for doing that, but the reason I prefer sailsjs because it is easy to use any npm module with it, with Meteor it is a bit tricky and on top of that it runs all of its code inside fiber. So is there any library I can use with it?

Comment: Trying to better understand your question.  What would be use case of syncing the database between client and server?

Comment: Say I have a mobile app using my rest api. When  it is off line it would use it local sqllite DB and when it get network connection it will sync all of its change to my rest server. You can do similar with couchbase or couchdb. But I am not using couch.

Comment: ok...got it. Seems like client-side responsibility.  Some type of binding with the network connection that triggers the request to the back-end to save/sync the data.